# How to make gnome-terminal cursor green

Tags: gnome-terminal, customization, cursor

I have customized my Terminal look a great deal now, and to add the finishing touches I wish to make my gnome-terminal cursor green (it is currently white), however there appears no way to do this in the settings GUI, so how could one achieve this? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME 3.16.

**Information Update:**

This is the current look of my Terminal:

[image: GNOME Terminal]

And I have configured this with:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;37m\][\[\033[00;32m\]\t\[\033[00;37m\]] \[\033[01;34m\]\u\[\033[00;37m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[00;37m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;32m\]$ '
```

In `.bashrc`.

Comment: Your font color is green but not you cursor?

Comment: @A.B.: Yes, I will update my question with more information.

Comment: @A.B.: I was not able to include the cursor in my screenshot, but it is a white block cursor so I am sure that you will know what it looks like.

Comment: Ok, I'm understand.

Comment: So you want it green and it's currently green?

Comment: @Zacharee1: No, it is currently **white** and I want it green. It is also camera shy so I couldn't include it in the screenshot. **;-)**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following command will change terminal cursor to `green`:

```
echo -e "\e]12;green\a"
```

Above command will print extra new line. If no new line required:

```
echo -ne "\e]12;green\a"
```

For permanent changes put above command in `.bashrc` file.

Further if you want to make your cursor visible or invisible:

```
tput cnorm  # make cursor invisible
tput civis  # make cursor visible
```

More information can be found at following link:

[How do I change the color of current cursor position indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494029/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-current-cursor-position-indicator)

Comment: How do I get the cursor to stay green *permanently*?

Comment: Put `echo -e "\e]12;green\a"` in `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Use `echo -ne` so that it doesn't print a newline. You can use any color with #RRGGBB notation. Make sure to surround the echo with a condition of the output being a terminal: `if [ -t 1 ]; then echo ...; fi` or the shell being interactive (`$-` containing `i`) or something similar, otherwise you'll break inbound scp or rsync (can't remember which, maybe both).

Answer (score 3):

Your text color is actually set to white, check it in the profile (menu edit/profile preferences/color ).  Your `PS1` explicitly returns the "current color" to green, so the text is green, but the `PS1` should have it's defining string end in `...]\w\[\033[00m\]\$` to return it to the default color.  Change the text color to green in the edit/profile preferences, and to avoid future confusion, use the above string to return to default.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
sudo nano #terminal-cursor-ds:#
```

and then type this in

```
cusor window color {
   {window frame cursor}
   {color="true"
   {color="green"
}
```

and then save the file, and then this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure term
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Because I am using GNOME `ubuntu-desktop` is not installed.